# I'm trying to write WebApi code to send an image file to Node.js using a POST request

Tags: c#, node.js, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing a WebApi program in C# that sends REST requests to a Node.js program written by a third party. I've got the source code for the Node program running on my laptop, but my knowledge of Node is limited. I'm using Fiddler to test sending requests. (Fiddler is similar to Postman and Curl.)

One of the things the WebApi program needs to do is to send an image file using a POST request. (The image file is associated with an order, so the order id is sent in the url.) When I send the request using Fiddler, Node returns OK and the image data is tranmitted successfully. When I send the request using the WebApi program, Node also returns OK, but the image data is not transmitted.

I would like to include some screenshots, but, apparently, I don't have enough credits to do that yet. In the successful Fiddler post, the Node.js console returns a json string containing UploadedFileMetaData data, followed by a Json string containing order_id and filename. In the WebApi case, UploadedFileMetaData is not returned. Instead, a file field containing byte data is added to the returned Json string.

I've listed below the steps that the WebApi program executes to send the request. Can anyone tell me what Fiddler is doing differently that causes the file data to be transmitted correctly? Thanks.

Variables are set with the following values:

```
string formDataBoundary = string.Format("----------{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid());
string contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + formDataBoundary;
string header = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\";\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n",
boundary,
param.Key,
fileToUpload.FileName ?? param.Key,
fileToUpload.ContentType ?? "application/octet-stream");
string footer = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
```

(The header string resolves to the following:
------------d19a2dfc4c734778b0849649617dff78
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Ducky.jpg";
Content-Type: image/jpeg)

A memory stream is created:

```
Stream formDataStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
```

The header, file contents, and footer are written to the memory stream:

```
formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(header), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(header));
formDataStream.Write(fileToUpload.File, 0, fileToUpload.File.Length);
formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(footer), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(footer));
```

The stream is dumped into a byte array:

```
formDataStream.Position = 0;
byte[] formData = new byte[formDataStream.Length];
formDataStream.Read(formData, 0, formData.Length);
formDataStream.Close();
```

An http request is created containing the following info:

```
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = contentType;
request.UserAgent = userAgent;  // Value doesn't really matter
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();    // Will not be used
request.ContentLength = formData.Length;
```

The request is posted:

```
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
}
```

I get the response using request.GetResponse(). It returns OK. The content type returned is "application/json; charset=utf-8". GetResponseStream returns 131,072 bytes.

Comment: Try to set ContentType="multipart/form-data"

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help. Note that Content-Type is set in two places. Before the boundary for the file contents, it's set as "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + formDataBoundary; Within the boundary, it's set as "image/jpeg". I tried changing the latter to "multipart/form-data", but, like I said, it didn't help. Also, setting the second instance of Content-Type to "image/jpeg" works fine in Fiddler.

Comment: I think you should try another way such as WebClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here's another simple solution for you.

```
 //// Upload api written in expressjs.


 var apiUpload = "http://localhost:3000/upload";
            var filePath =Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/1023.jpg");
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var responseBytes = client.UploadFile(apiUpload, "POST", filePath);
                var result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
            }
```

I created a simple upload API with expressjs and above sample worked properly with it.

Comment: That approach works, as long as the file I'm uploading is on my hard drive. Unfortunately, the files are on Azure Cloud. I tried using client.UploadData(), which accepts the file contents as a byte array, but that fails in the same way as the other method. I guess I could temporarily download the files to my hard drive before posting them. I'd prefer to avoid that, though.

Comment: Alex Nguyen -- I went ahead and wrote the cloud files to temp files on my hard drive, then used your code to post them. Worked like a charm. Thanks for your help.